# Matching OSC input in Max patch

Tags: osc, max-msp-jitter, ableton-live

I need some help as I’m stuck with trying to match an incoming OSC message to trigger an event. It’s probably quite simple, but I’m a beginner.

The incoming OSC message sends the zone number, user number and 0 or 1 if the zone is activated/deactivated. e.g. zone_1 1 0

I need to change the zone number for each instance of the patcher.
I don’t need the user info, but if it is needed in the sequence, then anything between 1 and 20 will create a match.
I need to toggle on /off using the last element in the message (0/1) if the zone number is matched.

I’ve put the rough outline of what I need in a patch, but I’m not sure I should be using zl slice and match, or how to get a combination of variables and non-variables to match.
I would appreciate some guidance very much!
[image: rough patcher layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that should work:

```
----------begin_max5_patcher----------
664.3ocyW0saaBCE9Z3o.4qypvlvOYR8IYZJxD7RcEXirMcIqpu6CNNzlzkX
nMA5tAjO13y224ed12CkK2wznfuG7i.Oum887.QcB7Nr1CUQ2sojpgigxaLF
o.svtknohKJYFXO7aBkMl2KslZ17.WrcshswX0HNjbW3hfnjrtWjk8OC94gu
gW.5Tl+32hH85zd2l80L6sfxohsnW+FsYeIrCB0I3Ee+tGKFI8Dre2psdUYX
6.nhzrx.7YIM4rjlLLoiRsbGHM4BjNzMoWzRxaEwapxYpOfe0AEIg.2v1Wwg
tnHI8hTridm5aqoJZEyvTqYBZtksgSoe+96+.N8QDoGtBrEqtK1gEI9hVDtv
LwA5+RIqz6qxkk2zTbRJt6UZjyPgKmhOwrlajzyx2nOKei.G8R2g93uPG8eJ
Czk7Mrf3aSYsDn5MdEv63TW7FuzYJ+zS7Rl3FUKOxx5jXH6dkSVimEVWwzZ5
V1+RaofstWZshoYBC0vkhinSzg51XfHgGd7JvtxRfGrUVcrzYkfrupBATijO
fQhXCwwooCajh9rFI6vAtKeb4FmkbsYVhmHCYqxfpgYgSP7zJ7coscQSRFdF
i3IObxoUBealgvVgMJdX9F8+P5y0kHjbRwBmrEeU4Av1smT79eCB.Um7SMCZ
YiZSuB5mQO3MfUvzFt.RDN9PjSNzC7hBl33oWK35tAZAVEdVGxXwS23iCimv
4COoi.O.nwyCdHiEOyj8AOF7LewOcSmcjq3B3AOe3YDlG.yyDbFMdlmv4wjc
gmOuU1HfS5rglwTJb9rMQSHZrswn00OwT5CWI.j191OJUcKSW.K4B6R3FQJ1
S79yCsiQTUauXSai3Fksa4trDj8SkELkngCm0uSyu3+W.shjk.
-----------end_max5_patcher-----------
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and giving me your input - it is much appreciated.   Unfortunately when I input the message zone_1 1 1 (not zone_1 as you have it) I get this error:  == doesn't understand "list".

Comment: I just added zl slice 1 to the message to use only the first bit, and then it seems to work.  I've never heard of half these objects, let alone know how to put them together.  Thanks again Mattijs.